# CSS Styling for anchor tag is not working

Tags: html, css

I have placed some links on a page added a css file to the html one, but the styling is not showing up.

HTML:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formatter.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <hr/>
        <div class="anch" style="text-align: center">
            <a href="admin_login.jsp" style="" >Admin</a>
            <a href="user_login.jsp">User</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

formatter.css:

```
body{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    background-color: silver;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.anch a:link, a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
.anch a:hover, a:focus, a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

When the above file is run, the body and h1 styles are visible but the anchor styles are not showing up. They appear in their default form (blue and underlined).
Here is an image of what shows up:

[image]

Comment: sudo classes are with colon : not dot .

Comment: It's `a:link`, not `a.link`.

Comment: Use the devtools style inspector to debug your CSS. There is a `:hov` button which opens a little panel where you can set the element state to `:hover`, for example, to help you test styles like this involving pseudo-elements. You will notice that your `a.hover` style is not being applied; perhaps you could proceed from there to figure out the problem.

Comment: @torazaburo Changed to `a:link`. Didn't make any difference. @Mani 's answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give style for `a`. then use colon for hover,active and others .

```
.anch a{

    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;

}
.anch a:link, a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
.anch a:hover, a:focus, a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css pseudo classes defines with colon `:` not with `.`

```
a:link, a:visited{
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}

a:hover, a:focus, a:active{
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
}
```

for more info please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class for anchor tag and u can use that when ever you need that.

```
<a href="somelink" class="archorCls">SomeThing</a>
```

in css

```
.archorCls{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. You used dot with a tag in css but : is used. I also gave a example for styling the anchor with css class. :)

```css
body{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    background-color: silver;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.anch a:link, a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
.anch a:hover, a:focus, a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
/* This is the css code for anchor styling */

.anchor{    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;}
/* When mouse hover the anchor class */
.anchor:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="anch" style="text-align: center">
<a href="admin_login.jsp" style="<!--You can use style here too -->" >Admin</a>
<a href="user_login.jsp">User</a>
</div>
</br> <!-- This br is for line space -->
</br> <!-- This br is for line space -->
</br> <!-- This br is for line space -->
<b> You can style your anchor tags with css class too. Here is the example</b>
</br> <!-- This br is for line space -->
</br> <!-- This br is for line space -->
</br> <!-- This br is for line space -->
<center>
<a href="admin_login.jsp" class="anchor">Admin</a>
<a href="user_login.jsp" class="anchor">User</a>
</center>
```